# Synchronize two PWM signals on two Raspberry PI

Tags: pwm

I wanted to know if it's possible to synchronize two PWM signals on two different Raspberry Pi?

If yes, what's the suitable module (Bluetooth, WIFI,...) the two Raspberries will be in 10m maximum from each other.

Comment: Do you just want them to have the same duty cycle, or actually sync up the beginning of their high (or low) phase?

Comment: It is clearly possible - but to what precision and for what purpose?  This is very broad at the moment.

Comment: Clearly possible remains to be seen. It's [non-trivial](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/3vbzxk/unstable_pwm_functions_with_raspberry_pi_2/) to achieve stable PWM on the Pi itself without resorting to external boards. Sync'ing two unstable PWM signals sounds difficult to me.